# The functor $\underline{\mathbf{R}}^if_*$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a proper morhpism of varieties, and $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $X$.

Then we have $f_* \mathcal{F}$ as a sheaf on Y and  we also have a higher derived functor $\mathbf{R}^i f_*{\mathcal{F}}$ which is also a sheaf on $Y$.

Moreover, we have another functor $\underline{\mathbf{R}} f_*$ which is the derived functor between derived categories of complex of sheaves (here $\mathcal{F}$ viewed as a complex in degree $0$):

$$\underline{\mathbf{R}} f_* : D(X) \to D(Y).$$

Then what is the usual meaning of $\underline{\mathbf{R}}^i f_*(\mathcal F)$? Here are two possible understandings:

(1) $\underline{\mathbf{R}}^i f_*(\mathcal F)$ is a SHEAF which is the $i$-th cohomology of $\mathbf{R} f_*(\mathcal F)$ (I feel that this is the common convention)

(2) Using the functor $\mathbf{R}^i f_*$ (this is not the left exact functor) to define the derived functor between derived categories $D(X) \to D(Y)$. Hence $\underline{\mathbf{R}}^i f_*(\mathcal F)$ is a sheaf of complex.

Comment: What is your functor $\mathbf R f_*$?

Comment: I did not write this functor in my question, if you mean $\underline{\mathbf{R}}f_*$, then it means you take an injective resolution of $\mathcal{F}$, and then apply $f_*$ to this complex, and the resulting complex is $\underline{\mathbf{R}}f_*(\mathcal{F})$ in $D(Y).$

Comment: Yes, that's the one I meant. I don't think that that's a derived functor, let alone a functor at all. For instance, take $f$ to be the identity: then you claim to be assigning an injective resolution functorially to every sheaf, and you run into a lot of problems because I don't think you can do that (unless you posess powers that I do not)... What reference are you using?

Comment: Please take a look at "Redisues and Duality" by Hartshorne page 87. ($D(X)$ is the derived category of complex of sheaves).

Comment: In your post, $D(X)$ is a category of complexes of sheaves...

Comment: @LiYutong: I think the point Bruno is making is just that you really need the _derived_ category in order for $\mathbf{R}f_*$ to be well-defined: there is a choice involved when you take an injective resolution, so the object you end up with by your construction will only be well-defined up to quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal@Asal Beag Dubh I see! I fixed that problem.

Comment: (1) is correct.  I don't even understand what you want to say with (2).

Comment: I want to use the higher derived image functor $\mathbf{R}^i f_*$ (as defined in Hartshorne Chapter III)to define a derived functor between $D(X)$ and $D(Y)$.